# Java JDBC adding automatic value to database

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working with Java JDBC with Apache Derby data base.
I have a table called `company`` with the values :
id, comp_name, password, email.

This method should create a new row of `company` with name, password, and email received from the user but the ID should be given automatically from the database and increment itself each time a new company is added to the database.

I just can't figure out how to make this work, I obviously get a error

> "column 'ID'  cannot accept a NULL value."

because the update occours before the ID is setted.

**Code:**

```
public void createCompany(Company company) {
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        con = ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO company (comp_name, password, email) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pstmt.setString(1, company.getCompName());
        pstmt.setString(2, company.getPassword());
        pstmt.setString(3, company.getEmail());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        rs.next();
        company.setId(rs.getLong(1));
        pstmt.getConnection().commit();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ConnectionPool.getInstance().returnCon(con);
    }
```

Comment: you do the insert before you set an id. why don't you just use autoincrement in your db?

Comment: yes , Auto increment do the trick

Comment: Go for auto increment

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, so simple and efficient!

Answer (score 2):

During creation of that table you have to write following DDL

```
CREATE TABLE MAPS
(
comp_id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
comp_name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(26)
)
```

Ref : https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop132.html

Answer (score 2):

You're doing *almost* everything right, you just need to let the database assign an unique ID to each inserted row:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A problem could be that you made a mistake by creating your table.
You could create your table like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE company
   (
      ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
      comp_name VARCHAR(50),
      email VARCHAR(50),
      password VARCHAR (50)
   )
```

IF you want other values to be not NULL you could add `NOT NULL` to their lines:

```
   password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
```

Delte your old table and execute the the SQl above on your DB. After that you can use your code without changes.